# How to start cinelerra on Debian?

Tags: debian, terminal, software-installation, runit

I have installed **Cinelerra** on **Debian 9**. I had to activate an additional **repository** for this, namely **deb-multimedia**, so that I can install it with `apt-get install`.

The installation worked and `which cinelerra` displays `/usr/bin/cinelerra` as location.

But, something is different than usual. Normally, I can run the newly installed program from the **graphical menu**, but this time **cinelerra** can not be found. 
So I examined `/usr/bin/cinelerra` and this file is already set as *excutable*, but I can not run it when I type its name in the **terminal** `./usr/bin/cinelerra` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Just type

```
cinelerra
```

in a terminal.

With `./usr/bin/cinelerra`, your shell will look for a folder called `usr` in the current directory, a folder called `bin` inside that, and `cinelerra` inside the latter; that’s not what you’re after here. If you want to specify the full path, drop the full stop:

```
/usr/bin/cinelerra
```